# How to change Url of a module frontend page which is generated by controller in magento?

Tags: magento

I am working on a module for video gallery. I can add category from the back end and can upload video with respect to that category.

I can modify the category listing page using `<frontname></frontname>` in config.xml

I have also noticed that the url of every category in category listing page is managed from model/category.php and the function is:

```
public function getCategoryUrl()
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('videogallery/index/cat', array('ci' => $this->getCategoryId()));
    }
```

where videogallery is module name, index is controller name and cat is catAction function in indexController.php, So my every category url is like www.domainname.com/module-Frontend-name/index/cat/ci/categoryId

**My question is how can I remove this "index/cat" from every category url?**

Comment: The code you have listed is not native Magento code. Perhaps you could post the contents of the videogallery module's `IndexController`?

Answer (score 0):

if "cat" is the name of your action inside IndexController, there's no way to remove it, unless you code a mod_rewrite rule.

Is this what you need?

Comment: Did you mean that, when I will add a video category then I will have to generate a mod_rewrite rule using code for that category or after adding the category I will have to add a mode_rewrite rule from the magento backend manually.